# Is it safe to chain multiple transformations onto a single-subscription Stream in dart?

Tags: dart

After reading about [single-subscription vs. broadcast streams](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/broadcast-streams/) in dart, I realized I am chaining a bunch of transformations (Stream.map/where/transform) on the result of File.openRead (a single-subscription Stream).  AFAICT this hasn't caused any problems.  Is this safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem with single-subscription streams AFAIK.

Comment: To expand on Guenter's answer: the transformations don't have any effect until someone starts listening. This is similar to Iterables.